# keycloak connection url ldap with Bind Type 'none'

Tags: active-directory, ldap, keycloak

I'm using keycloak and I could connect to ldap with Bind Type 'simple', but in a case I wanna connect to ldap with Bind Type 'none' because I don't have admin information for using in Bind DN and Bind Credential.
now my question is if I can use Bind Type 'none' and what's the condition for using this case.

thanks

Comment: none - means anonymous LDAP authentication. You should check how it works with your LDAP implementation but I've never seen that in production.

Comment: I don't want to check with administrator user, is there any implementation that would help me check the user authentication without domain admin rights ? @KostiaShiian

Comment: just create a user in AD, by default it will be only in Domain Users group. Definitely, do not use users from Domain Admins for this.